# NMDS plot in R: how to plot species in different colours and sites in different shapes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I am performing a nmds in R using metaMDS from the vegan package.
I have 8 variables and two sites.
I am not familiar with editing of graphics and I do not know how to customize my plot.
I was able to change colours depending on the site, but what I would like to have (and I really don't get how to do it) is a plot with different shapes for each variable and different colours for each site.
My approach was the following:

```
library(vegan)
nmds_results <- metaMDS(data_nmds[ , 3:10], distance = "bray")
data.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(nmds_results))
data.scores$site <- rownames(data.scores)
data.scores$grp <- data_nmds$station
species.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(nmds_results, "species"))
species.scores$species <- rownames(species.scores)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  +     geom_text(data=species.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,label=species),alpha=1) +  # add the species labels
  +     geom_point(data=data.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,shape=grp,colour=grp),size=1) + # add the point markers
  +     geom_text(data=data.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,label=site),size=1,vjust=0) +  # add the site labels
  +     scale_colour_manual(values=c("SG01" = "red", "SG05" = "blue")) +
  +     coord_equal() +
  +     theme_bw()
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I do not understand what are the variables that you want to color?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with an reproducible example.

I have tried to guess what you want to plot but I am not sure.

```r
library(vegan)
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : permute
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : lattice
#> This is vegan 2.5-6
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2)
community_matrix <- matrix(
   sample(1:100,300,replace=T),nrow=10,
   dimnames=list(paste("community",1:10,sep=""),paste("sp",1:30,sep="")))

example_NMDS <- metaMDS(community_matrix, # Our community-by-species matrix
                     k=2, trace = 0) # The number of reduced dimensions
data.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(example_NMDS))
data.scores$site <- rownames(data.scores)
data.scores$grp <- rep(c("1", "2"), each = 5) 
species.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(example_NMDS, "species"))
species.scores$species <- rownames(species.scores)

ggplot() + 
  geom_text(data=species.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,label=species), alpha=1) +  # add the species labels
  geom_point(data=data.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,shape=as.factor(grp), colour=as.factor(site))) + # add the point markers
  geom_text(data=data.scores,aes(x=NMDS1,y=NMDS2,label=site, colour=as.factor(site)), vjust=0) +  # add the site labels
  #scale_colour_manual(values=c("1" = "red", "2" = "blue")) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very useful! Do you think that it would be possible to represent each species (sp1, sp2 and so on) using different shapes and to colour the shape with the colour of the site? In your experience, do you think that is appropriate to perform a nmds using environmenta paremeters instead of species?